# GDPR and personal data

Tags: flutter, security, google-cloud-firestore, data-security

I have an application mobile developed by the flutter and Firestore dB.

I read somewhere that the app must respect the GDPR.

My Firestore content infos user (email, PhoneNumber, image,) and infos for their stores (phones, images, position...)

which data have I to encrypt to respect this GDPR and what also I have to do,

Thanks in advance

Comment: The app must respect the GDPR if you want to do business in Europe. The GDPR has nothing to do with encryption. If your app is available in Europe I suggest you read the GDPR and if in doubt, contact a professional to explain it.

Comment: thanks for your response, yes my app is in Europpe, my data in firestore is not encrypted it will not pose a problem ?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

You can find most relevant information [here](https://ec.europa.eu/info/law/law-topic/data-protection/reform/rules-business-and-organisations).

> The GDPR applies to:
>
> - a company or entity which processes personal data as part of the activities of one of its branches established in the EU, regardless of where the data is processed;
>
> - or
>   a company established outside the EU and is offering goods/services (paid or for free) or is monitoring the behaviour of individuals in the EU.

So it most likely applies to you.

The GDPR is not about *encryption*, it is about *consent*. I strongly suggest you read the whole page I linked, there is no way I could explain the GDPR in a single post here.

If in doubt, ask a local lawyer.